# How to get value from nsobject in swift 4

Tags: xcode, swift4, nsobject

I have multiple objects which I have to append in an array without duplicity. Following is my object,

```
 let slotParamsObj: [String: Any] = [


        "bookdate" : currentDate,
        "device_id" : deviceId,
        "id" : mallID,
        "location_id" : locationId,
        "maxSlot" : maxSlot,
        "price" : price,
        "time" : time,
        "total" : total,
        "type": type,
        "quantity" : quantity


    ]
```

after that,

```
 if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: slotParamsObj, options: .prettyPrinted),
        let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {

            if cartSlotArr.count > 0{

                for result in 0...cartSlotArr.count{


                    let obj = cartSlotArr[result] as? NSObject
                    print(obj)


                    let d =  obj!.value(forKey: "id") // I am getting error in this line.
                    print(d!)


                    if mallID == mallID{


                        if time == time{

                            self.cartSlotArr.removeAll()
                            self.cartSlotArr.append(str as? NSObject)

                        }


                    }

                    else {
                self.cartSlotArr.append(str as? NSObject)

                    }
            }


        }

            else {

        self.cartSlotArr.append(str as? NSObject)

        }

    }
```

I have to get value of "id" from object to compare and append data accordingly in cartSlotArr without duplicity of "id". So for that I am creating NSObject again in for loop and try to getting value of "id". But while I am doing this I am getting an error - "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key id."

Comment: Don't use the type `NSObject` in Swift at all, cast the type to the actual Swift type. And consider that you might get an out-of-range crash.

Comment: Thanks Vadian, which would you like to suggest for better result ?

Comment: The information in the code is too vague (and quite confusing) to give a concrete suggestion